# Filter table rows that contain at least X observations with value larger (or equal) than Y

Tags: r, filtering

I am trying to filter for table rows that contain at least 3 observation with values larger or equal to 0.7. Here is an example of what I would like to do in **R**:

```
   sA  sB  sC  sD  sE  sF
g1 0.1 0.2 0.8 1.2 0.5 0.0
g2 0.7 0.3 0.9 0.8 0.5 1.0
g3 0.2 0.3 0.8 0.9 0.5 0.0
g4 0.5 0.4 0.9 0.7 0.5 1.0
g5 0.2 0.2 0.8 0.9 0.5 0.0
```

Filtering will result in:

```
   sA  sB  sC  sD  sE  sF
g2 0.7 0.3 0.9 0.8 0.5 1.0
g4 0.5 0.4 0.9 0.7 0.5 1.0
```

Can someone help me out on this problem?

Answer (score 4):

If x is your data,

```
   > x[rowSums(x >= 0.7) >= 3,]
            sA  sB  sC  sD  sE sF
        g2 0.7 0.3 0.9 0.8 0.5  1
        g4 0.5 0.4 0.9 0.7 0.5  1
```

Answer (score 0):

If a is your table name.

You can access the requested lines with:

> a[apply(a>=0.7,1,sum) >=3,]
>
> ```
>        sA  sB  sC  sD  sE sF
>    g2 0.7 0.3 0.9 0.8 0.5  1
>    g4 0.5 0.4 0.9 0.7 0.5  1
> ```